# Mixing and aligning non-Smart fields in a SAPUI 5 Smartform

Tags: sapui5

The attached screen below works just fine but underneath the covers I have a slight problem ^^

[Smartform with both simple and smart fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ybkM.jpg)

Behind the view there's a smartform (no annotations used). Field "Agreement Action Type" and the last two pairs of fields are not smartfields (found no "smartcombo" or something similar to use) they are just pairs of labels and comboboxes and here comes the issue. While the smart fields were all perfectly aligned, comboboxes (aka simple fields I suppose) were not aligned along. In order to solve this for the moment, I used a couple of SAPUI5 formatting classes and...width declaration in pixels in the combo definition within the view. Results works fine, even in different size monitors but, even though I'm currently in the process of learning and understanding the technology, I already know that the latter is a crime against SAPUI5. Is there a way to align smart and simple fields in the same view (or an equivalent dropdown control for smartforms alternatively) or I will have eventually to get rid of my smartform (losing small bonuses like the togglable attribute) and use a simple form instead?

Thanks for taking time to read it.

Regards,

Greg

Answer (score 2):

The GroupElement aggregation manages the SmartLabel for you so try to remove the label inside the [GroupElement](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartform.GroupElement/function%20Object()%20%7B%20%5Bnative%20code%5D%20%7D) aggregation like this:

```
<smartForm:GroupElement label="Label">
    <Input type="Text" value="someValue"/>
</smartForm:GroupElement>
```

On the contrary, if you want to change the appearence of your SmartField, you can use [ControlType](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.ControlType) to configure the internal control.